# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) on Raspbian

Tags: ssh, debian, permissions

I'd like to connect to my CentOS server via SSH, but Permission denied error was shown.

- RPI to Server with "ssh foo.bar.com" command -> FAILED ("Permission denied" was shown)
- RPI to Server with "ssh-agent", "ssh-add" and "ssh foo.bar.com" commands -> SUCCEEDED
- PC to Server with "ssh foo.bar.com" command -> SUCCEEDED

How can I connect to server with "ssh foo.bar.com" command?

Details are as follows.

### Raspberry PI -> Server

I tried to connect to my CentOS server via SSH from my Raspberry PI (Raspbian wheezy).
But Permission denied error was shown.
How can I connect to my server?

```
d_komatsuda@raspberrypi ~ $ ssh -v foo.bar.com
```

Then I got following error (excerpt).

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/d_komatsuda/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/d_komatsuda/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/d_komatsuda/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Permissions are as follows:

```
d_komatsuda@raspberrypi /home $ ls -ld d_komatsuda
drwxr-xr-x 4 d_komatsuda d_komatsuda 4096 Oct 12 06:52 d_komatsuda
d_komatsuda@raspberrypi /home $ ls -ld d_komatsuda/.ssh
drwx------ 2 d_komatsuda d_komatsuda 4096 Oct 12 06:08 d_komatsuda/.ssh
d_komatsuda@raspberrypi /home $ ls -l d_komatsuda/.ssh
total 16
-rwx------ 1 d_komatsuda d_komatsuda  405 Oct 12 04:57 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 d_komatsuda d_komatsuda 1743 May 25 18:39 id_rsa
-rwx------ 1 d_komatsuda d_komatsuda  405 Oct 12 04:55 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 d_komatsuda d_komatsuda 1106 Oct 12 05:50 known_hosts
```

Why "Enter passphrase for .ssh/id_rsa:" isn't shown?

In addition there are authorized_keys and id_rsa.pub because I'd like to access from my PC  via SSH.

### Raspberry PI -> Server : With ssh-agent

I couldn't connect to my server in above way, but with ssh-agent, I could connect.

```
d_komatsuda@raspberrypi ~ $ ssh-agent bash
d_komatsuda@raspberrypi ~ $ ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for .ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: .ssh/id_rsa (.ssh/id_rsa)
d_komatsuda@raspberrypi ~ $ ssh -v foo.bar.com
```

Following messages was shown (excerpt).

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to foo.bar.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Last login: Sat Oct 12 20:49:30 2013 from xxxxxx.yyyyyy.jp

SAKURA Internet [Virtual Private Server SERVICE]

[d_komatsuda@www1447ui ~]$
```

Why could I connect to my server with ssh-agent, but couldn't without ssh-agent?

### My PC (Cygwin) -> Server

From my Cygwin console, I can connect to my server correctly.

```
d_komatsuda@i7-975 ~
$ ssh -v foo.bar.com
```

Then I got following messages (excerpt).

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/d_komatsuda/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/d_komatsuda/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to foo.bar.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Last login: Sat Oct 12 17:03:13 2013 from xxxxxx.yyyyyy.jp

SAKURA Internet [Virtual Private Server SERVICE]

[d_komatsuda@www1447ui ~]$
```

Please give me some advice.

### Logs from server side

I got following logs (/var/log/secure) when I tried to connect to the server from the RPi and got "Permission denied" error.

```
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16829]: debug1: Forked child 16857.
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16857]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: rexec start in 7 out 7 newsock 7 pipe 9 sock 10
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16857]: Connection from yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy port 57716
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Oct 12 21:36:30 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: KEX done
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: userauth-request for user d_komatsuda service ssh-connection method none
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "d_komatsuda"
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "xxxxxx.yyyyyy.jp"
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: userauth-request for user d_komatsuda service ssh-connection method publickey
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0/0)
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: trying public key file /home/d_komatsuda/.ssh/authorized_keys
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 500/500 (e=0/0)
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: trying public key file /home/d_komatsuda/.ssh/authorized_keys2
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: Failed publickey for d_komatsuda from yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy port 57716 ssh2
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16858]: Connection closed by yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16858]: debug1: do_cleanup
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: do_cleanup
Oct 12 21:36:31 www1447ui sshd[16857]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
```

Comment: Add the logs from the server side (`/var/log/auth.log`) during the failed login attempts after you have set `LogLevel DEBUG` on the server configuration (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and restarted it.

Comment: @dawud Added the logs (server side). "Failed publickey for ..." means the pair of the public key and the private key is invalid? (But MD5 of id_rsa is same on RPi and my PC)

Comment: @lain Thank you for pointing them out. I read them. My question was certainly hobby question (not professional question)... I'll examine using Super User or U&L.

Comment: The error message: "Failed publickey for d_komatsuda" is the interesting bit there.

Comment: @dawud I solved myself. I found [this site](http://wupamo.blogspot.jp/2011/07/ssh.html) (Japanese). According to it, id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in ~/.ssh must be pair. In my case, id_rsa.pub is the public key for the authentication between my PC and RPi. id_rsa is the private key for the authentication between {my PC or RPi} to my server. So they're not pair. I renamed id_rsa to id_rsa_vps and did `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_vps foo.bar.com`, then I could connect to my server from RPi without ssh-agent! Thank you.